# write into csv file in php

Tags: php

I have to create and write into a csv file. Now I tried with the following code:

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');  
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"');    
$data = array (
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w+');  
foreach($data as $line){
    $val = explode(",",$line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

It gives me my source file code also in the csv file? How can I solve this?

Comment: Where does your `$header` variable come from?

Comment: sorry it is not required. i edited the code

Comment: have you tried exit(); after fclose()?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in `<?php` and `?>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first header to `header('Content-type: text/csv');`

Answer (score 1):

header() needs to come after the array and fopen

try this:

```
$data = array (
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w+'); 
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');  
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"'); 
foreach($data as $line){
    $val = explode(",",$line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

$data = array (
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"');


$fp = fopen('php://output','w');
foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_map('utf8_decode',array_values($line)), ',', '"');
}
fclose($fp);
```