# How to send form data to CSV

Tags: php, javascript, forms, csv

I have a specific request from a client that a newsletter signup be sent to a CSV file. I am a noob when it comes to anything backend, let alone frontend development.

I have a template that I am working from and can't make sense of the way it delivers the values.

The form code is quite simple

```
<form action="" method="post" class="signup" id="newsletter-form">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="signup_name" id="signup_name" class="required" value="Your Name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="signup_email" id="signup_email" class="required" value="Your E-mail" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="signupSubmit" id="submitform" />
    <div id="newsletter-msg-wrapper" style="position:relative; clear:both; width:100%;">
        <div id="newsletter-loader"></div> <span id="newsletter-msg"> &nbsp; </span>

    </div>
</form>
```

Then I have this .js file that seems to be handling the post

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var contactFormDefaults = new Array();
    contactFormDefaults['name'] = 'Your Name';
    contactFormDefaults['email'] = 'E-mail';
    contactFormDefaults['subject'] = 'Subject';
    contactFormDefaults['message'] = 'Message';
    contactFormDefaults['msg'] = $('.contactForm span#msg').html();

    $('.contactForm input[type="text"], .contactForm textarea').focus(function () {
        $(this).addClass('inputHighlight').removeClass('errorOutline');
        if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
            $('.contactForm span#msg').html('This is a required field.').removeClass('errorMsg successMsg');
        } else {
            $('.contactForm span#msg').html(contactFormDefaults['msg']).removeClass('errorMsg successMsg');
        }
        if ($(this).val() == contactFormDefaults[$(this).attr('id')]) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
    $('.contactForm input[type="text"], .contactForm textarea').blur(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('inputHighlight');
        $('.contactForm span#msg').html(contactFormDefaults['msg']).removeClass('errorMsg successMsg');
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val(contactFormDefaults[$(this).attr('id')]);
        }
    });

    $('.contactForm input[type="text"], .contactForm textarea').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('inputHighlight');
    }, function () {
        $(this).not(':focus').removeClass('inputHighlight');
    });

    $('.contactForm').submit(function () {
        $('.contactForm .submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#msg').html('<img src="images/loader-light.gif" />').removeClass('errorMsg successMsg');
        var isError = false;
        $('.contactForm input, .contactForm textarea').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('required') && ($.trim($(this).val()) == contactFormDefaults[$(this).attr('id')] || $.trim($(this).val()) == '')) {
                $(this).addClass('errorOutline');
                $('#msg').html('There was an error sending your message. Please try again.').addClass('errorMsg');
                isError = true;
            }
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'email') {
                var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
                if (reg.test($(this).val()) == false) {
                    $(this).addClass('errorOutline');
                    if (!isError) {
                        $('#msg').html('Please enter a valid e-mail address and try again.').addClass('errorMsg');
                    }
                    isError = true;
                }
            }
        });
        if (isError) {
            $('.contactForm .submit').removeAttr("disabled");
            return false;
        } else {
            var name = $('#name').val(),
                email = $('#email').val(),
                subject = $('#subject').val(),
                message = $('#message').val();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: false
            });
            var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message + '&ajax=1';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../myform.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function (msg) {
                    // Check to see if the mail was successfully sent
                    if (msg == 'Mail sent') {
                        // Update the progress bar
                        $('#msg').html('Message sent.').addClass('successMsg');
                        // Reset the subject field and message textbox
                        if (contactFormDefaults['subject']) {
                            $('#subject').val(contactFormDefaults['subject']);
                        } else {
                            $('#subject').val('');
                        }
                        if (contactFormDefaults['message']) {
                            $('#message').val(contactFormDefaults['message']);
                        } else {
                            $('#message').val('');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#msg').html('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.').addClass('errorMsg');
                        $('.contactForm .submit').attr("disabled", "");
                    }
                    // Activate the submit button
                    $('.contactForm .submit').removeAttr("disabled");
                },
                error: function (ob, errStr) {
                    $('#msg').html('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.').addClass('errorMsg');
                    //Activate the submit button
                    $('.contactForm .submit').removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

If possible I'd love to know how to make this all function and what I am not seeing here and how this all can be written into a CSV file.

A full view of the site and code can be viewed here:

www.cndnsd.com/ClientAccess/Newmarket/FinalSite/index.html

The form is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: *"and can't make sense of the way it delivers the values."*: Please be more specific about what you want to know. I don't think anyone will go through that wall of code and explain every line. Overall this question might be too broad. We are not going to implement this feature for you.

Comment: If they are signing up to a newsletter, then the data must be stored somewhere! ie database. To create the csv, query the database and loop through the records using `fputcsv()` to create the file OR just ouput the data to the screen with the correct headers, so it becomes a forced download instead (generated when required).

Comment: @Waygood: I think the point is to store the data in a CSV file, instead of database. User fills out form -> data is sent to the server -> data is stored in CSV file.

Comment: in that case open the csv with `fopen('file with path', 'a')` to append to the end of it, then `fputcsv()` the new data (making sure you have write permissions on folder and file)

Answer (score 0):

in your myform.php , receive all the data (email, name etc) and start creating your CSV file. It is a simple operation and not that complicated.

For CSV file writing, please check out these posts on stack overflow:

[write into csv file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579201/write-into-csv-file-in-php)

[Creating csv file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501463/creating-csv-file-with-php)

Also do some googling.

Hopefully this will help you.