# Convert a coma separated string to csv

Tags: php

Is it possible to convert a coma separated string to a csv file in php?

```
str = "apple, orange, banana, lychee, grapes, pineapple, strawberry, mango";
```

Comment: In the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Is it just me or is Comma separated string and CSV more or less the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write into csv file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579201/write-into-csv-file-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
$str = "apple, orange, banana, lychee, grapes, pineapple, strawberry, mango";
$data = str_getcsv($str);
print_r($data);
```

To save `$data` to a file you can use `fputcsv`

```
//Open file
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

//Add $data to file
fputcsv($fp, $data);

//Close file.
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks +10. What about giving it a file name? Basically I will be saving this on the server.

Comment: I updated my answer with how to save a single line to file. If you want to save more just add more `fputcsv()` or include in a `for-loop` between `fopen` and `fclose`.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly happens is I create this coma separated string on the fly. Then I'm looking for a way to save this coma separated string as a CSV file named `converted.csv` on the same location where the php is.